# What is the History of Election/Voting system in Ancient India?

Tags: scripture, vedas, history

**Wiki Source:**

> In recent days Post-independence India held it's first elections. The
>   rest of the India voted only in February–March 1952 for the Lok Sabha
>   and Vidhan Sabha elections. Polling was held between 25 October 1951
>   and 27 March 1952. The very first votes of the election were cast in
>   the tehsil (district) of Chini in Himachal Pradesh.

I heard about **‘Janapada’, It means “People’s Republic, where people come together to choose their leader.**

Did Electoral system does exist in Ancient India Mythology? If Yes, What are the Qualification for contestants?

Any Scriptures mention about Election system in Vedas or Ramayana/Mahabharata?

Comment: Interesting Qn. People's "Democracy" is mostly a failed or failing political or social system. It's least likely to have existed in ancient India. May be if it would have existed at some point of time at some place, then it would have vanished in few decades or centuries, hence living no reference [in scripture].

Comment: Or this one [Where do the Vedas support democracy](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17954/where-do-the-vedas-support-democracy)

Comment: @iammilind thanks for sharing generous your thoughts. Because of Democracy we have many changes it's not failed. Few People who elected in higher position failing systems, change will be happening one way or other.

Comment: @SreeCharan Oh brilliant work, before commenting you should read question fully.

Comment: I read your question completely. You took the example of recent elections(1950's).  If you are asking for election process, there was no election process or contestants. There were only kings who ruled according to people's wishes. Princes became eligible by gaining people's support. And also Janapada means not people's republic. It means the pada(words) of Jana(people) Janapada means people's  words which literally means folklore. There was democracy but not elections or electoral process.  There might not be election reference in scriptures.

Comment: @SreeCharan You said might not be, so there should be a chance? If we don't know about history, can mention as per my knowledge. Just look in to history many occasions people never wishes so called kings then after their sons. They just followed with respect to Rightful heir, but there should be some occasions they might needed election process for choose rightful leader (King). Isn't it?

Comment: Janapada refers to a geographical entity - a piece of land with a boundary , like a district or mandal. It does not mean people's republic. Ancient India was governed by monarchy. The kshatriya caste ruled the people under advisory and guidance from the brahmin caste. There were no elections in government. Selections were made for spouses, appointment to ministerial offices etc. but not towards ascension to the throne.