# Was dwarka a democratic state?

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, puranas

I heard that yadu who was son of yayati had a curse from his father that neither he, nor anyone from his generation can become king ever. So, whole region ruled by yaduvanshis was like democracy? As shree krishna even married satyabhama, who was daughter of a very rich merchant for some political reasons as i heard.

Comment: check my answer here - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/53012/21696

Comment: Multiple questions in single question.