# Is "Democracy" naturally in accordance of "Dharma" (righteousness)?

Tags: belief, dharma, caste-system, dharma-shastras

"Democracy" was not famous until last few centuries. Famous political system till then was "Dynastic". i.e. the dynasty was not only prevalent among the ruler clan (i.e. *Kshatriya*), but also intellectuals & priests (*Brahmana*), business class (i.e. *Vaishya*) and the worker or server class (i.e. *Shudra*).

In such social systems, generations after generations, people would try to perfect only certain skillset without giving way to their passion towards other fields.

Democracy is different in following ways:

- It gives freedom of speech and action to everyone (limited by constitution)
- It's contagious -- i.e. From topmost system (ruling) to the bottom most system (family), everyone can express their right/wrong views without fear
- Everyone are treated as same; e.g. the vote/opinion of intellectual is not counted higher than the normal worker
- Ruler is obliged to people and not the other way around
- Ruler is non permanent & volatile; The advantage of his/her genes are not trivially carry forwarded; Their children have to start from 0 to get into power

Above points, if read carefully looks lucrative on face value, but are also detrimental towards basic social system. A good answer may point out nature of *Dharma* and how the democracy would satisfy/dissatisfy it?

**Can democracy naturally uphold *Dharma*?**  (naturally = without "if"s)

Related: [Democracy in Hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/13533/1049)

Comment: It is against our religion. Nothing is possible in our religion if everybody is treated as equal.

Comment: Clearly not.It is incompatible with the varna system which is one of the pillars of dharma. Another eg is the court interfering with hindu temples (sani singanapur ruling is in direct opposition to hindu dharma. Court ruling on trivandrum padmanabha swamy temple is in violation of temple rules).The bullets  you mention are not in opposition of the practice of monarchy in India.Kshatriya dharmas are very detailed,many & nuanced.Princes trained to become kings;not just waited around to be crowned. Our dharma also states that the sins of the praja fall on the king.So our dharma is more stringent.