# How to reconcile Vasishta's statement on eldest son inheriting throne with Dasratha's proclamation?

Tags: ramayana, vashishta, dasharatha

As seen in this [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/13536/18974) Dasratha invited the assembly to debate his decision to coronate Rama and presented the pros and cons of Rama's candidature with a neutral viewpoint.

But as per [verse 35 of the 110 Ayodhya kanda sarga](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/ayodhya/sarga110/ayodhya_110_frame.htm), Vasishta says

> इक्ष्वाकूणाम् हि सर्वेषाम् राजा भवति पूर्वजः |

> पूर्वजेन अवरः पुत्रो ज्येष्ठो राज्ये अभिषिच्यते || २-११०-३५

> The eldest son only becomes the king in the entire Ikshvaku race. When the eldest son exists, the younger son will not become a king. The eldest son only is anointed to the crown.

Now how does one reconcile the above two incidents. If eldest son was to become King in Ikshvaku then why did Dasratha go on to explain pros and cons of Rama being the heir ?

On a related note, if it was given that eldest son was to be crowned king then Manthara would not have waited till the Dasratha's announcement to poison Kaikeyi's mind.

Comment: 3 reasons - 1. It's a sign of humility of king, and his respect for subjects. 2. To set example of how future kings should behave in case any son becomes a bad person (like king Vena). 3. Most importantly, he wanted to hear about his son's greatness from people - there can be no greater joy for father. In fact, people said 'Old man, it's time for u to go to forest and make Rama king', to which Dashrath replies 'What fault do you see in me, and what qualities do you see in him', and then people respond with Rama's greatness. Source - Upanyasa

Comment: eldest song becoming king is norm. not just in Ikshvaku vamsha but almost entire Bharat varsha of all lineages. but there can be exceptional circumstances - what if the eldest son dies or blind (e.g. chitrangadha & dritharashtra in mahahbarat) ? does it mean there will be no king ?

Comment: Yes you are right there is contractual treaty between lkekya kingdom and ayodhya  singed by dasaratha that son born to kekeyi would be made king regardless of order on account of marriage of kekeyi manthara is aware she wanted to invoke at the time coronation of rama.there is lot of politics not only that during putra kamayesti yagna dasaratha doesn't want to share the pyasaa prasad  to kekeyi because of this agreement

Comment: He announce coronation rama when baratha is away to kekeyi kingdom he wanted to coronation rama before bharaths return and also he didn't invite janak for coronation because if he invited janak than he needed invite kekaya also he wanted coronation of rama tone done in swift and fast manner before kekaya objects and state the contract

Comment: @Prasanna R - where did you read about such a contractual treaty? Even if there was a treaty are you suggesting that the noble Dasratha was being clandestine about Rama's coronation ?

Comment: @ram - on 3 i agree that dasratha wanted to hear praise but the response of the people "goto forest", and dasratha's inquisitive response " what fault you see in me" , seem like additional rasa

Comment: Dasaratha is not all noble infact he pleads kekeyi to ask some other boon to kill innocent even he is prepared to do instead sending rama to forest.. where is the nobility of king here. King is to protect citizen not like despot.. why he is in hurry to coronation when bharatha and satrughnu is away? tell me? And also he didnt consult vasistha on dates of coronation but he ask the general public instead does rama fit enought rule. Who will refuse.

Comment: . As expected everyone wanted Rama to be king this is word that he wanted to  here from public and right next he want to coronate.. you know it was occasion of Ramas Birthday i believe for that he had decorated all of ayoydha not usual.. he had in mind that tommorrow is cornation cermony we will decorate the city under the guise of birthday

Comment: @Carmensandiego, a person could be experiencing many thoughts & emotions in a second. It's not possible to capture each and every one in a shloka, so some non-contradicting emotions can be assumed by readers/listeners/commentators